# Directly go to Product Detail page on click the category?

Tags: magento

In my store, one of the category has only one product. Is it possible to take the user directly to the product detail page of this one product whenever they click this category in the nav bar? i want to use some code to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the product grid or list foreach loop in /app/design/frontend/default/[template]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<?php if ($_productCollection->count() == 1) {
$url = $_product->getProductUrl();
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url); }
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductUrl() on a non-object in

Comment: it shows the above fatal error? should i foreach the $_productCollection?

Comment: the url will have ?___SID=U. is there a way to remove it? thank you

Comment: in your list.phtml go down to where either the grid or list foreach loop is happening. Inside the foreach loop you will find getProductUrl, put it under there. 

try this for removing SID 
http://www.peeledcarrots.com/magento-removing-session-id-sidu-from-the-url/